# cant run any c/c++ program

Tags: c++, c, clion

Anytime I try to run a simple C or C++ program in CLion or emacs, no output shows up.

EDIT: Using virtual environment, C was not installed properly.

Comment: Read [ask] an provide all information with a [mcve] **No images of text!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLion doesn't ship with a C/C++ compiler. You need to install your own compiler, and then set it up with CLion.

For windows, you can install:

- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (make sure you select gcc-core and g++ during setup)

CLion will detect these environments automatically during installation if you set them up in their default locations.

Comment: So, after installing MinGW f.e, would I have to reinstall CLion?

Comment: You can also go into settings and set up the build environment from there, but I've found that the easiest way is to get MinGW installed before CLion.

Comment: Warning on MinGW. Read carefully because there are a bucket load of MinGW variants out there, and some of them are built around older versions of GCC (4 vs 7). As you might expect, MinGWs built around GCC4 aren't going to be able to compile some newer code, leading to confusion if your reading materials and tutorial sources are up-to-date.

Comment: It's my first time with C and using IDE's as a whole (I use text editor + cmd typically), so would you just recommend Cygwin?

Comment: The problem with using Cygwin to build for release is that the built binaries depend on the cygwin runtime, so you'd need to include the cygwin dll with your distribution.

Comment: Some of what you say is a bit above my head, which way should I go here: https://gyazo.com/3d779532abd935b04566e6286ae4b7d8

Comment: "depend on the cygwin runtime": Cygwin has a .dll file that everything you compile with it depends on. Your programs won't run without that .dll file.

Comment: your screenshot: You didn't select dev tools when installing cygwin. You need to rerun setup and install the correct packages. Look in the development section for gcc core and g++

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for your help